# How does the mybatis parameter replacement work in @SelectProvider

Tags: java, ibatis, mybatis

I've in inherited some code that I'm trying to understand and any searching I do to find something on `@SelectProvider` turns up a whole lot of nothing.

**Java DAO**

```
@SelectProvider(type = CategoryDaoSelectProvider.class, method = "findByParentIdAndName")
Category findByParentIdAndName(@Param("parentId") Long parentId, @Param("name") String name);
```

**Select Provider**

```
public class CategoryDaoSelectProvider {
    public static String findByParentIdAndName(Map<String, Object> params) {
        Long parentId = (Long)params.get("parentId");  // WHY IS THIS HERE???

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Category ");

        if (parentId == null) {
            buffer.append("WHERE parentId IS NULL ");
        } else {
            buffer.append("WHERE parentId = #{parentId} ");
        }

        buffer.append("AND LOWER(name) = LOWER(#{name}) ");

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

What purpose does the param parentId serve in this code? As far as I can tell it never actually does anything unless somehow magically the #{parentId} is replaced with the value. Is this param just not used in this situation?  Where does `mybatis` actually do the injections into the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SelectProviders receive parameters in 2 ways: as items in the params Map argument and as #{parentId} (in your example). You code shows parentId being checked before it is used in the select statement. The parentId variable is needed because you can't query #{parentId}.

Btw, this isn't the best implementation of a SelectProviders, you're supposed to use SELECT(), WHERE() and SQL() at the end to return the compiled statement. I guess your example works too.

Comment: I understand what you're saying...Just want to point out for anyone reading this that the line I asked about is not doing anything.  We get the value for parentId but do nothing with it.  In this code as it sits this line of code serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite that piece of code as follows, which is perhaps a bit clearer? The actual value of `parentId` is indeed not necessary, but the info on whether or not the parameter is present is required.

```
 // ...
 boolean hasIdParam = params.containsKey("parentId");

 StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
 buffer.append("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Category ");

 if (!hasIdParam) {
    buffer.append("WHERE parentId IS NULL ");
 } else {
    buffer.append("WHERE parentId = #{parentId} ");
 }
 // ...
```